# Is the storage of data acquired, with an HTTP-Client such as Axios, in the context-api state a good practice?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-context

i've been developing an app using react 16.8 and to avoid importing Axios in every component i started making use of the context API to hold data from all my requests on its internal state and reference this data in the component where i need it with the `<Consumer/>`, but the number of properties in the state grew considerably, i wonder if this is ok, and if  it is should i clean the state after using the data where i needed, in a method like `ComponentWillUnmount`?

```
Class ContextProvider {
state = {
prop1: [],
prop2: [],
prop3: [],
{...n}
 }

getProp1Data = () => {
Axios.get(url)
.then(res => this.setState({prop1: res.data})
}

{.... n}

}
```

Comment: `but the number of properties in the state grew considerably` -- The general principle is that, instead of using prop1, prop2, ..., you use an array of prop.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Redux since with Redux you can travel between the state history in development, and re-evaluate the current state from the action history when the code changes. In this way you be able to import Axios only once to your middle ware and to make your code more clear.

In case you consider to use ComponentWillUnmount you won't be 'cleaning' your state since setState() can't be called on this life cycle method. ComponentWillUnmount is related to the competent itself on the DOM and not to the state. There's not a problem with your props being 'grew considerably' and you may use as many as you like.